# Parse query in Swift - Can't seem to sort the query from newest to oldest

Tags: swift, parse-platform

```
self.messageFromId.removeAll()
self.messageFrom.removeAll()
self.taskTitle.removeAll()
self.message.removeAll()
self.taskId.removeAll()
self.messageId.removeAll()
self.messageType.removeAll()


if PFUser.current()?.objectId! != nil {

    let query = PFQuery(className: "Message")
    query.addDescendingOrder("createdAt")

    query.limit = 10

    cur = PFUser.current()!.objectId!

    query.whereKey("messageTo", equalTo: cur!)
    query.findObjectsInBackground(block: { (objects, error) in

        if let posts = objects{
            for object in posts {
                if let post = object as? PFObject {

                    let query2 = PFUser.query()

                    query2?.whereKey("objectId", equalTo: post["messageFrom"] as! String)
                    query2?.findObjectsInBackground(block: { (objects, error) in

                        if let posts = objects{
                            for object in posts {
                                if let post2 = object as? PFObject {

                                    if post2["handle"] as! String == "new$!" {
                                        self.messageFromId.append(post["messageFrom"] as! String)
                                        self.messageFrom.append(post["messageFrom"] as! String)
                                        self.taskTitle.append(post["taskTitle"] as! String)
                                        self.message.append(post["message"] as! String)
                                        self.taskId.append(post["taskId"] as! String)
                                        self.messageId.append(post.objectId!)
                                        self.messageType.append(post["messageType"] as! String)
                                    } else {
                                        self.messageFromId.append(post["messageFrom"] as! String)
                                        self.messageFrom.append(post2["handle"] as! String)
                                        self.taskTitle.append(post["taskTitle"] as! String)
                                        self.message.append(post["message"] as! String)
                                        self.taskId.append(post["taskId"] as! String)
                                        self.messageId.append(post.objectId!)
                                        self.messageType.append(post["messageType"] as! String)
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        }

                        self.tableView.reloadData()
                        self.refresher.endRefreshing()
                    })

                }
            }
        }

    })
}
```

Results seems to come back in a random order, not sure why ?  Am I doing the query within the query correctly ?

I did add : query.addDescendingOrder("createdAt") at the beginning of the query.  It's not working

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using: `query.order(byDescending: "createdAt")` instead.